# python, add lists to csv by columns, with list extracted dynamically from other data

Tags: python, list, csv

my problem is: I want to add a number of lists in to a csv file by columns, for example i have these lists:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, t1]
[0, 3, 3, 2, 3, t2]
[5, 3, 2, 1, 2, t3]
```

add them to csv file like this:

```
1   0   5
2   3   3
2   3   2  
3   2   1  
3   3   2  
t1  t2  t3
```

i checked on some other posts to use zip:

> zip(a, b, c) gives you a list of rows: [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]

But my lists are dynamically extracted from other data source,
e.g. from a dictionary:

```
for x, y in cpu_dict.items(): 
    y.append(x)               
    # y is a number list [1,2,2,3,3] etc. and x is a string 't1' etc.
```

the dictionary cpu_dict is something like:

```
{'t1': [3,3,4,2,2,1,3], 't2': [2,4,3,2,1,2,3], 't3': [2,2,3,4,5,2,3] ... many more...}
```

all the number lists are in same length. How should I use zip() for this situation?

Any helps? Thanks in advance.

=================================

got the solution, thanks kroolik.

Comment: can you show what is `cpu_dict` exactly ? you want to use zip to add to y list in your example ?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't transpose with the zip solution

Comment: A dictionary has no ordering; in what order do you expect the dictionary values to become the columns?

Comment: i added the style my my dictionary. I thought the zip() would work with the lists that are available, and merge them together. The doesn't matter about the ordering really, once i put the different keys at the bottom which will appear in the same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `izip`:

```
>>> cpu_dict = {'t1': [1,2,3,4,5], 't2': [6,7,8,9,10], 't3': [11,12,13,14,15]}
>>> list(izip(*(y + [x] for x, y in cpu_dict.iteritems())))
[(6, 11, 1),
 (7, 12, 2),
 (8, 13, 3),
 (9, 14, 4),
 (10, 15, 5),
 ('t2', 't3', 't1')]
```

`y + [x]` evaluates to `[1,2,3,4,5,'t1'], [6,7,8,9,10,'t2'], [11,12,13,14,15,'t3']`.
The order of columns is arbitrary (thats how regular dicts work).

You can then feed it to `csv.writerows`, or each row separately to `csv.writerow`.

If you want columns to be ordered,  try this one instead:

```
>>> cpu_dict = {'t1': [1,2,3,4,5], 't2': [6,7,8,9,10], 't3': [11,12,13,14,15]}
>>> sorted_items = sorted(cpu_dict.iteritems(), key=lambda x: int(x[0][1:]))
>>> list(izip(*(y + [x] for x, y in sorted_items)))
[(1, 6, 11),
 (2, 7, 12),
 (3, 8, 13),
 (4, 9, 14),
 (5, 10, 15),
 ('t1', 't2', 't3')]
```

The key to use `izip` with dynamical number of lists, is the [arbitrary arguments list notation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists). It allows you to turn an iterable of values into positional arguments, i.e.:

```
foo(*[1,2,3,4,5,6,object()]) == foo(1,2,3,4,5,6,object())
```

Comment: thanks for your response. i changed my code, needs to add this: from itertools import *. but the lists are still not added into csv correctly.

Comment: @user2068965, How does your code look like now? Simple `writer.writerows(izip(*(y + [x] for x, y in sorted_items))` should do the trick.

Comment: hi, i still didn't get right, and i am not sure about my writer part. it gives a error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Link to my code in dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ojil5co1sk76my/bowtie_extract_time.py

Comment: @user2068965, you are missing one closing parenthesis in the last line.

Comment: hi, thanks very much, i got it working, without column ordered, but its ok i can do it by hand.